# Когда удвоенные согласные произносятся коротко?

Tags: фонетика

Есть два слова — "Алла" и "миллион". В слове "Алла" -лл- произносится как [л:], а в слове "миллион" — как [л].

В каком случае удвоенные согласные читаются долго, а в каком коротко?